# Disabled UK Citizen

Tags: united-kingdom, immigration

In Liverpool -1973, my brother (Geoff) was disabled in a car accident. Shortly afterwards, our family emigrated to Canada. If Geoff moves back to the UK, will he be eligible for health care and housing assistance?

Thanks

Hyku

Comment: How old was Geoff when he emigrated?  Can you explicitly confirm he is still a British Citizen?

Comment: Hello, Geoff was 14 years old, he has his British Birth Certificate - and his UK Passport. (He also has Canadian medical records.)  Thanks.

Comment: I think the answer to you question is 'yes' but perhaps not immediately. He would have to be resident in the UK for 3-6 months (I'm not sure which). He would otherwise be responsible for all bills up until that point, and those charges are not retroactively resolved once residency is attained.

Answer (score 2):

[This page](https://www.gov.uk/guidance/nhs-entitlements-migrant-health-guide) (from www.gov.uk) says:

> For secondary care services, the UK’s healthcare system is a
>   residence-based one, which means entitlement to free healthcare is
>   based on living lawfully in the UK on a properly settled basis for the
>   time being.

So provided he moves back permanently, he will be eligible for free health care.

---

https://www.gov.uk/housing-benefit/eligibility says:

> Usually you will not get Housing Benefit if:
>
> - your savings are over £16,000 - unless you get Guarantee credit of Pension Credit
> - you live in the home of a close relative
> - you’re a full-time student - unless you’re disabled or have children
> - you’re residing in the UK as an European Economic Area jobseeker
> - you’re an asylum seeker or sponsored to be in the UK
> - you’re subject to immigration control and your granted leave states that you cannot claim public funds

None of which would apply to your brother (and the last three bullet points all relate to immigration status).

[This page](https://www.citizensadvice.org.uk/benefits/coming-from-abroad-and-claiming-benefits-the-habitual-residence-test/british-and-irish-citizens-claiming-benefits/) from Citizens Advice suggests that he may have to live in the UK for three months before he is entitled to housing benefit.

---

All of this looks very positive - however I would suggest that your brother does not emigrate to the UK on the say-so of some random guy on the internet.  Moving is going to involve some expenses - I would try and find someone who knows their way around the benefit system, and can offer advice for *his* situation, and then pay for that advice.  This might be a lawyer, or it might be some sort of advisor.

[This page](http://www.adviceuk.org.uk/looking-for-advice/find-advice/) might help find one.

Comment: Unfortunately, that gov.uk page doesn't really cover the situation for UK citizens returning from long periods abroad. This AgeUK fact sheet explains that housing benefit is subject to the "habitual residence test" which hyku's brother may not meet initially. He will need to plan how he will support himself, potentially for 6 months or more, without state assistance. https://www.ageuk.org.uk/information-advice/money-legal/benefits-entitlements/returning-to-the-uk-after-living-abroad-heading/

Comment: @MJeffryes Yes.  That's what the Citizens Advice page said too.

Comment: Thanks very much guys. Now we can start planning.  Cheers